# java PrintWritter or BufferedOutputStream method flush not working on windows 2012

Tags: java, windows, printwriter

i have problem only with Windows 2012 server.
I am trying write a big file to disk using PrintWritter or BufferedOutputStream, the problem is that in Windows 2012 when call a method flush() to send the data stream to file not is working.
Only write the data to file when close() method is called.
The problem is that the data save in memory and consumed a lot of file.
In my Windows 7 or 8 is working fine.
Some idea issued with windows 2012?
Thanks,

Simple example:

```
File file = new File("myFile.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)), "UTF-8"), 1024 * 4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            out.write("Some info here");
            if (i % 300 == 0) {
                out.flush();

            }
        }
        out.close();
```

Comment: 'The data save in memory and consumed a lot of file' is nonsense.

Comment: did you got solution to this probelm? I am facing simillar issue? My memory size is close to 2GB and any file above this size is not getting created? I am getting stream data from source with size upto 10 GB

Answer (score 2):

1. `flush()` does work, even on Windows 2012. However `PrintWriter` does swallow exceptions: you need to check for those with `checkError()`. It might be better to just use the `BufferedWriter`.
2. A maximum of 4096 or 8192 characters, not sure which (or whatever you specified in the `BufferedWriter`), is buffered, so your memory loss is elsewhere.

Comment: i tried using BufferedWriter but some result. not working.

Comment: BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)), "UTF-8"),1024*4);

Comment: Are you closing the `BufferedWriter`? And why the `BufferedOutputStream`?

Comment: Yes after close() the data write to disk fine. The problem is that all data first save in memory. 2 millons of line in memory. Not is flushing.

Comment: Please post your code. The situation as you describe it is impossible.

Comment: Hello EJP i added a simple code that not is working in win 2012.

Comment: 1. The file size always is 0 byte during tasks. (flush no take effect)
2. The file fill data only when call close() method. (when end the task)
3. The monitor of memory increase and increase during task and back to normal on close() method.